# Specifying amanda TCP ports

Tags: linux, backup

I'm running amanda and I need it to use a set range of ports to communicate with some hosts beyond a firewall. Using udp port 10080 for the initial communication is fine, but it's currently trying to establish tcp connections on random unreserved ports to pull the backup data.

I've tried setting unreserved-tcp-port in amanda-client.conf on both the client and server to 10081,10089. I also tried setting it in amanda.conf but it didn't recognize the keyword. I also tried running amdump backupname --with-tcpportrange 10081,10089 but it doesn't run at all.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If unreserved-tcp-port isn't recognised as a valid keyword you have quite an old version of Amanda - 2.5.1 or earlier.

```
amadmin yourconfname version
```

will show version and compile-time options.

If you do have version 2.5.2 or later then
    amgetconf yourconfname unreserved-tcp-port
will show value that your system is using, eg

```
[root@issbs4 src]# amgetconf UNIX-RL unreserved-tcp-port
11000,11040
```

I'm guessing old version and way forward is to upgrade.